# R: Unlist pairwise comparisons p-values into dataframe

Tags: r

I can apply the following code to apply a pairwiset.t.test function on each column of a certain dataframe, A, against a dependent parameter, DEP.

```
apply(A, 2, function(x) pairwise.t.test(DEP, x, p.adj = 'bonferroni')$p.value)
```

The output for this function results in a list type data. Something like the following shows:

```
$A
    1        2         3         4  
1  0.7236751 NA        NA        NA  
2  0.7236751 0.7236751 NA        NA  
3  0.7236751 0.7236751 0.7236751 NA  
4  0.7236751 0.7236751 0.7236751 0.7236751  


$B
          0
1 0.7236751
```

I would like to ask if there's a way to combine the two list mode data such that:

```
       1         2         3         4         5
1  0.7236751 NA        NA        NA        0.7236751
2  0.7236751 0.7236751 NA        NA        NA
3  0.7236751 0.7236751 0.7236751 NA        NA
4  0.7236751 0.7236751 0.7236751 0.7236751 NA
```

The output of `dput(apply(A, 2, function(x) pairwise.t.test(DEP, x, p.adj = 'bonferroni')$p.value))`
is as follows:

```
Dimnames = list(c("10", "11", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "23", "31", "33", "34", "36", "39", "40", 
"42", "43", "45", "46", "47", "49", "50", "51", "52", "54", "59", 
"60", "63", "64", "66", "70", "73"), c("6", "10", "11", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "23", "31", "33", "34", 
"36", "39", "40", "42", "43", "45", "46", "47", "49", "50", "51", 
"52", "54", "59", "60", "63", "64", "66", "70"))), Gender = structure(0.723675133647025, .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list("1", "0"))), .Names = c("A", "B"
))
```

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(apply(A, 2, function(x) pairwise.t.test(DEP, x, p.adj = 'bonferroni')$p.value)`. We cannot tell if that $A element is a dataframe or a matrix, and it does matter. Perhaps merely: cbind(obj$A, obj$B)

Comment: FYI this is not the complete dput output.  Looks like you left off some stuff at the beginning.